# Parcel importing material-components-web scss files installed to node_modules not working

Tags: sass, parceljs, material-components-web

I have installed `material-selected` as instructed [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select), by running the command:

```
npm install @material/select
```

I have included the html for select and set the width of it. And in my `sass` file I have imported material styling like suggested in the documentation:

```
@use "@material/list/mdc-list";
@use "@material/menu-surface/mdc-menu-surface";
@use "@material/menu/mdc-menu";
@use "@material/select/mdc-select";
```

But, when I am trying to build my project with parcel, I get the error:

```
Can't find stylesheet to import.

@use "@material/list/mdc-list";
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/scss/app.scss 1:1  root stylesheet
```

How am I suppose to import this stylesheets?
I have tried with tilde operator as well:

```
@use "~@material/list/mdc-list";
@use "~@material/menu-surface/mdc-menu-surface";
@use "~@material/menu/mdc-menu";
@use "~@material/select/mdc-select";
```

But, that didn't help either, then I got::

```
  @use "@material/density/functions" as density-functions;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  node_modules/@material/list/_mixins.scss 22:1 @use
  node_modules/@material/list/mdc-list.scss 21:1 @use
  src/scss/app.scss 1:1 root stylesheet
  Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.

  @use "@material/density/functions" as density-functions;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  node_modules/@material/list/_mixins.scss 22:1   @use
  node_modules/@material/list/mdc-list.scss 21:1  @use
  src/scss/app.scss 1:1                           root stylesheet
```

Also in my vs code editor I get warning that the @use is unknown rule:

```
 Unknown at rule @usescss(unknownAtRules)
```

I am not sure why do I get that.

Comment: did you ever figure it out? I have the same issue.

Comment: no, unfortunately I still have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

When using Parcel bundler you'll also need to provide import path configuration. See [Parcel docs](https://parceljs.org/scss.html) for more details on how to configure Sass.

Add `.sassrc.js` file to your project root folder and include following lines:

```
const path = require('path')

const CWD = process.cwd()

module.exports = {
  "includePaths": [
    path.resolve(CWD, 'node_modules'),
    path.resolve(CWD, 'src')
  ]
}
```

Here is a [full example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/desert-unique-battery?path=.sassrc.js%3A10%3A1) on Glitch.